# Please delete an answer that is locked

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I'd like to withdraw my answer from a question by deleting it. The answer is locked so I can't access it. In addition, the flag button is greyed out so I can't raise a flag to have it deleted.

Please delete this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30020905/608639.

(**EDIT**: the original question is now closed, and the answer was deleted by George. Many thanks to George).

Comment: I fail to see why that answer should be deleted.

Comment: @jww, that looks like a good answer, and we usually refrain from deleting good content, even when prompted to do so by the original author. Would disassociating your account from that answer be enough?

Comment: @Frédéric - well, I feel the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I provided the answer to show why the code is *not* incorrect, and show it is more suited for Code Review. I'm not sure its a good idea to promote answering off-topic questions (though I do so on occasion). To answer your question, yes - please disassociate me from the question.

Comment: The correct action for off-topic questions is to vote to close, not post an answer. What changed your mind about the question's suitability for SO? Also, if the question is off-topic, shouldn't you be asking about deleting/closing the question, not its answers?

Comment: @nhgrif - *"The correct action for off-topic questions is to vote to close, not post an answer."* - I agree. So are you making the argument to delete the answer? I made the compromise to disassociate from the question, but maybe I should insist on the delete. *"...also, if the question is off-topic..."* - I'm done with this debate.

Comment: If you just want to ask the moderators to delete/disassociate your answer, you should just flag the question with that as a custom comment, not open a question on Meta\* - most contributors here (myself included) can't help either way. If you'd like to have a discussion about whether it (or the question) should be deleted, please clarify this question accordingly.

Comment: If the question doesn't belong on SO, then it should be closed and perhaps eventually deleted. I'm not making a statement of opinion on whether or not it belongs, just explaining the appropriate course of action for questions which do not belong. If the question does not belong, you should probably elaborate on that, but please note that SO's meta doesn't say anything about "Questions on-topic at other SE sites are off-topic here" and SO/SE meta discussions indicate that is not the case (and it is not a **close** reason). So why is it a bad fit for SO?

Comment: @jonrsharpe he stated the flag button is unavailable to him.

Comment: @jww surely you can still flag the question, though?

Comment: `Its my answer, and I'm free to do with it what I wish.`  Ehhh.... it's kind of Stack Overflow's answer at this point

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - If George (or someone else) would unlock it so I have access to it, then I would prove you wrong ;)

Comment: @jww - and don't be surprised if the community or a moderator intervenes and proves you wrong.

Comment: With respect to whether the question is on topic, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181569/why-do-we-even-have-code-review) is a related discussion about a very similar situation.

Comment: Everyone - the question has been disposed. A few of the community members closed it and George deleted the answer in question. My thanks to George. Lets dispose of this one too since its just a sink of time and effort.

Answer (score 25):

I think it might be time to walk away from this for a little while and calm down. You obviously have strong feelings about whether the question belongs on Code Review or not, but deleting a good answer out of spite isn't the correct response.

You left a good answer to a question. You believed the question belonged on Code Review. Others did not. This could have ended there, but the debate got out of hand in the comments, and those were cleaned up. Again, it could have stopped there, but you then edited meta-commentary into the answer. This commentary didn't belong there, so a moderator rolled that back to just that original factual answer.

Once you overturned a moderator's rollback and again introduced the meta-commentary to the answer, the post was locked by that moderator and the discussion directed here. This is standard procedure when dealing with rollback wars involving moderators.

The answer is still a good one. You've had your say as to where you think the question belongs, and members of the community have had a fair chance to debate this. Whether or not that answer is worthy of staying on the site is completely separate from that debate.

I wouldn't let the emotions you're feeling about this debate dictate whether that good answer should be deleted. It doesn't help anybody to remove content like that from the site.